# Update year using a month as criteria

Tags: mysql

I need to update the year to add ten years.
As a criteria, the year and the month should be less than the current year.
Example:
2005-05-10 - 10.05.2015
2006-06-10 - 10.06.2016
2006-**09**-10 - 2006-09-10 * remains in 2006 as we are in the month 09 and year 2016.

```
UPDATE BW
    SET Date_3 = SUBDATE(Date_3 , INTERVAL -10 YEAR)
     WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Date_3 , '%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m') 
     AND DATE_FORMAT(Date_3 , '%m') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m');
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: the second condition does not work

Comment: what you mean by that? what's your desired result and what's you are getting currently?

Comment: Your question says **add** ten years. Why are you using `SUBDATE()`, which subtracts?

Comment: With MySQL you can just use `Date_3 + INTERVAL 10 YEAR`. I've never come across an instance where I have to use `SUBDATE()`, but that could just be the versions of mysql and queries I've been using